# Web interface for Gitolite

Tags: user-interface, gitolite, frontend

Are there any front end apps or web interfaces for Gitolite? I'm about something not for repository viewing but for access management.

Answer (score 14):

[**GitLab**](http://gitlabhq.com/) not only provides a GitHub-like basic frontend, but also issue trackers and merge requests.

Comment: It does not use gitolite anymore

Answer (score 6):

I found two such projects on GitHub:

[Gitolite-Manager](https://github.com/JustLikeIcarus/Gitolite-Manager) is a *"Web Interface to manage Gitolite"* and *"allows you to add users and create repositories"*. It's written in JavaScript and runs with node.js.

[gitolite-webui](https://github.com/narkisr/gitolite-webui) is *"a simple webui for adding keys to gitolite managed repositories"*, written in Clojure.

Both of the project repositories have had activity in Sep and Oct 2011. I haven't actually tried out these projects nor had any contact with the authors.

There's also [oligui](https://github.com/kureikain/oligui) which claims to be *"a very simple web interface to control Git Olite configuration file"*, but there isn't any Gitolite-touhcing code (yet?) in the repo. Written in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting answer for an old thread. 
[Gitblit](http://www.gitblit.com/) is another one.